# When calling multiple C++ functions from QML and the first function contains a connect call, the QML continues before the callback is triggerd

Tags: c++, qt, api, qml

For a customer of mine I'm creating a mobile app within the QT framework.

The snippets code will be posted at the bottom of the question.

In the app on the login page I'm doing an API call to a REST API running on phalcon PHP, the call works and returns the data just fine, however I'm using getter and setter functions for the API result so the result is accessible in the QML files.

The problem I'm facing is that when the connect function is called the QML starts calling the next functions in line while the API call is not yet finished.

To get an idea of the flow:
1 *click login button*->2 *send api call*->3 *receive API result*->4 *parse the result and make it accesible globally*->5 *get the result in QML*->6 *continue with the QML code and login*

The incorrect flow it's currently doing:
1 *click login button*->2 *send api call*->3 *continue with the QML code*->4 *stop because you're not yet logged in*->5 *receive API result*->6 *parse the result and make it accesible globally*->7 *Stop*

I've already tried to put in sleeps and waits after step 2 in the flow to see if the callback get called before, but the callback will wait as well.

Code snippets:

QML:

```
onClicked: {
    _Login.setUsername(inputBox.text)
    _Login.setPassword(inputBox2.text)
    _Login.buttonClicked()
    _Login.checkThread("derp")
    if (_Login.getResult()) {
        if (_DbManager.addId()) {
            var id = _DbManager.getId()
            _Login.setUniqueID(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QUrl>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class Login : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit Login(QObject *parent = 0);
    QMutex mutex;
    QString username = "";
    QString password = "";
    QString uniqueId = "";
    bool result = false;

signals:

public slots:
  bool getResult();
  void buttonClicked();
  void setResult(bool result);
  void setUsername(QString username);
  void setPassword(QString password);
  void parseNetworkLoginResponse(QNetworkReply* finished);
};

#endif // LOGIN_H
```

C++:

```
    void Login::buttonClicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Clicked is called";
    QJsonObject jsonObj;
    jsonObj["username"] = this->username;
    jsonObj["password"] = this->password;

    QJsonDocument doc(jsonObj);
    QByteArray BAJson = doc.toJson();

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(parseNetworkLoginResponse(QNetworkReply*)));

    QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("API URL"));
    req.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    manager->post(req, BAJson);
    qDebug() << "Clicked is finished";

}

void Login::parseNetworkLoginResponse(QNetworkReply* finished)
{
    qDebug() << "parse is called"
    QByteArray result = finished->readAll();
    setResult(newResult);
}

void Login::setResult(bool result)
{
    qDebug() << "set result is called";
    this->result = result;
}

bool Login::getResult()
{
    qDebug() << "get result is called";
    return this->result;
}
```

Comment: We can't run this code.

Comment: @Mitch this should be enough to understand what is happening and in what flow it is happening, The only thing that might be missing is the main.cpp how the Login class is exposed withing the QML, but that's quite basic.. If there is more more data required, just tell me what I'm missing and I'll add it.

Comment: Just use `Q_PROPERTY`s or a signal to inform the QML when the request is done instead.

Comment: Another remark: It seems like you're leaking the `QNetworkAccessManager` right now: If multiple users log in, you create a new one for every log in, and they live until the `Login` class is destoryed. If you destroy the `Login` class right after the login is finished this is fine, but I'd still consider making the `QNetworkAccessManager` a member of the `Login` class itself.

Comment: @Corristo could you elaborate that answer please?

Comment: Well, as you already figured out, the `QNetworkRequest` is performed asynchronously and the execution continues even though the request is not yet finished. Once it is, the signal/slot connection will invoke `Login::parseNetworkLoginResponse`. So you could emit a signal there, and connect to it from QML in order to update it only once the request is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `QNetworkRequest` executes asynchronously, you won't have a result immediately after returning from `Login::buttonClicked`. So you need to inform QML once the result is ready. You can use a signal for that.

In your `Login` class header add

```
signals:
    void resultReady();
```

and modify `Login::parseNetworkResponse` to

```
void Login::parseNetworkLoginResponse(QNetworkReply* finished)
{
    qDebug() << "parse is called"
    QByteArray result = finished->readAll();
    setResult(newResult);
    emit resultReady();
}
```

Then you can use QMLs `Connections` component to add a signal handler in QML that performs the desired action once the signal is received:

```
onClicked: {
    _Login.setUsername(inputBox.text)
    _Login.setPassword(inputBox2.text)
    _Login.buttonClicked()
    _Login.checkThread("derp")
}

Connections {
    target: _Login
    onResultReady: {
        if (_Login.getResult()) {
            if (_DbManager.addId()) {
                var id = _DbManager.getId()
                _Login.setUniqueID(id);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Here, depending on what it does, maybe the call to `checkThread` also needs to be part of the new signal handler instead of the original `onClicked` handler.

However, I don't understand why that latter part even is done in QML, it would make much more sense to have the `Login` class perform the call to the `DbManager` and have it update its `uniqueId` itself instead of by QML.

Comment: I shall try this right now and I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: @TheCad There might be syntax errors in the QML since I didn't test it, but thats the general idea

Comment: This worked perfectly like a charm! I didn't know it was possible like this to send signals like this through qml. Thanks a lot!